# Detect If Changes Have Been Made To Input Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, field

I have a input form with Jquery & PHP what I am trying to archive is if a user makes any changes to the form and they try to navigate away from the page A popup message comes up saying if they want to exit and discard changes or stay and save the changes first?

How could I archive this thought I did it but all my current one is doing is checking if the fields have data in them but i'm making use of the value='' feature in HTML to get the current settings in the database.

Only run this function if submit has not been pressed yet.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Try to use as much language specific words as possible and please show what you already tried. Also an example input and expected output would be great

Comment: I tried to explain it has best as possible what I mean is when A user types any data in to a input field and hasn't pressed the saved button and they try to navigate away from the page I need a popup error saying "are you sure you want to exit and discard changes"

Answer (score 2):

1 Create a flag that specifies whether something was changed:

```
var changes = false;
```

2 Bind an event listener to every single input and textarea that sets changes to true:

```
$('textarea,input').on('keypress change input', function() {
    changes = true;
});
```

3 Bind an event listener to `onsubmit` that sets changes to false:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    changes = false;
});
```

4 Bind an event listener to onbeforeunload that returns the question if there are changes:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () { 
    if (changes) return "Do you really want to leave?"; 
});
```

Demo on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/VYKeu/

Comment: Only other isse I have been having is since i'm using JQuery to submit the form realtime it's having trouble detecting if I pressed submit or not :/

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @user279297 Simply reset `changes` in your AJAX request or whatever you are using.

Comment: Don't want to sound like a noob lol how would I reset the changes.

Comment: @user279297 Not *the* changes, the variable `changes`, look at my third code block.

Comment: would i change that to true instead of false

Comment: @user279297 If it is set to `true` the browser will ask before leaving the page.

Comment: Ok think I get it now so I would set it to false then or something like that

Comment: Thanks ;)
That method has minor bugs which is not a big deal let me know if you want to know the bugs I encountered otherwise it works fine ;)
Thanks again!

Comment: didnt work! something so easy looking turns in to a mission :/

Comment: Nevermind I try work it out myself or might stop using javascript